# How can I resize a datagridview to fit the content?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, size

I am using a datagridview using c# and Winforms.

The dgv has 4 columns which are read from a database. Two columns are hidden, one is an image icon and fixed width. The fourth is a variable length text string.

The column width of the icon is set to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader.

The variable column is set to AllCells, though I have also tried Fill.

I really want to use AllCells which would shrink the column width down to the length of the longest text. The problem is that when I do this the vertical scrollbar stays out on a limb at what I presume is the dgv Width. The grid itself displays correctly but leaves a lot of blank space between the end of the last column and the scrollbar.

I have tried computing the size I want the dgv to be but it seems to ignore the sizing - or at least not set it to what I want it to be.

Anyone have any idea what I am missing?

Thanks
Steve

I realise what the issue is now. I really want to build the dgv on the fly and set its size based on the data I have read from the database. It would seem that the dgv size has already been fixed and can’t be changed programmatically. Unless that is when I initially load the parent form. A bit crummy really. I want to be able to build the dgv based on the selected index of a combobox. The dgv would potentially have different widths because the variable text could be very different depending on the selection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fit DataGridView width and height to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661303/how-to-fit-datagridview-width-and-height-to-its-content)

Comment: Add `yourDataGridViewName.AutoSize = true;` in your form constructor. Note that you won't find the `AutoSize` property of the DGV in the property grid at design time but you can set it in code.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the DGV itself wider on the form, or make the columns resize (which may cause a horizontal scrollbar to appear because the DGV is a fixed width/anchored to the form) within the DGV? Perhaps some screenshots of what you have and what you want would help