# Autosize a DataGridViewComboBoxCell which uses custom painting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, autosize, datagridviewcomboboxcell

My `DataGridView` has a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` on it. This is my custom cell painting handler:

```
private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1 && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
        //e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Color c = Color.Empty;
        string s = "";
        Brush br = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
        Brush brBack;
        Rectangle rDraw;

        rDraw = e.CellBounds;
        rDraw = Rectangle.FromLTRB(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);

        brBack = Brushes.White;
        Pen penGridlines = new Pen(dataGridView.GridColor);
        g.DrawRectangle(penGridlines, rDraw);
        g.FillRectangle(brBack, rDraw);
        penGridlines.Dispose();

        if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
        {
            ComboboxColourItem oColourItem = (ComboboxColourItem)dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
            s = oColourItem.ToString();
            c = oColourItem.Value;
        }

        int butSize = e.CellBounds.Height;
        Rectangle rbut = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Right - butSize,
                                       e.CellBounds.Top, butSize, butSize);
        ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton(e.Graphics, rbut,
                   System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.ComboBoxState.Normal);


        if (c != Color.Empty)
        {
            SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(c);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left + 6,
                                         e.CellBounds.Top + 5, 10, 10);
            g.FillRectangle(b, r);
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r);
            g.DrawString(s, Form.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black,
                         e.CellBounds.Left + 25, e.CellBounds.Top + 3);

            b.Dispose();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

When I go to autosize my populated column by double-clicking the right edit of the DVG this is what happens:

[image: Autosize]

How do I adjust the behaviour so that when autosizes it takes into account the combo dropdown?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the width of that drop-down button known outside of that Paint event?

Comment: @DonBoitnott No, but the width is specified in the paint event as `e.CellBounds.Height` so perhaps we have it anyway?

Comment: I don't use DGV, so I don't know what events you might have available, but I'd be looking for (in order):  a direct override of the column auto-size; something that fires after a resize; or `ColumnWidthChanged`.  You should be able to use one of those to figure out if it's the column you care about and add a bit more width for your button.  The AutoSize is never going to know about it, so you have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you double click on a column header divider to make the column auto size, it makes the column width equals to widest cell.  Width of a combo box cell in auto size mode is calculated using:

- Width of formatted value
- width of combo box button
- cell style padding
- error icon width
- some extra padding around text and button and icon

**Quick Fix**

In your case those colored rectangles occupy space but their width and spaces around them will not be calculated when calculating auto size of cell.

As a simple solution you can add some padding to the column. You can do it in designer, by editing columns and set the padding in `DefaultCellStyle` for the column. Also using code you can write for example:

```
column.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(16,0,16,0);
```

**Long term solution**

If the column is a reusable column type, I recommend you to create your custom column type. Then you can encapsulate painting logic and calculating size and some other features in your custom cell. If you decide to create your custom cell, you will find these methods related to the problem useful:

- [`DataGridViewCell.GetPreferredSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.getpreferredsize(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [`DataGridViewCell.Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.paint(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Works great.

Comment: put `ComboBoxRenderer.DrawDropDownButton...` at the end of drawing, the button should be rendered above text. Currently as you an see the text is drawn over combo box button. You should draw combo box button after you draw text.

Comment: I got you now. Good thinking! I took _wnd_ to mean _window_ and not _end_ :).

Comment: ;) yes it was a typo. I removed the comment.

Comment: Just one side effect of using padding. When I go to edit and display the combo it is not full cell width because of the padding either side. Understand? At the moment my columns are wide enough I do not need resizing. But the answer might need to be revised to allow for the fact that the combo will now be too small.

Comment: Using the padding is a good workaround for changing preferred width of cell. As another option consider creating a custom column type. This way you have full control over column size.

Comment: Take a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37648097/3110834). It's not about custom combo box cell, but it shows you how to control the size when using autosize style for a cell. Hope you find it useful :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114255/discussion-between-andrew-truckle-and-reza-aghaei).